# Create a new column with word counter

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), alternativenum = c(342, 5921), text = c("one text here","another text here also"))
```

How is it possible to add a new column in this dataframe where it will contain a word counter for every row using the text column?

Example of expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), alternativenum = c(342, 5921), text = c("one text here","another text here also"), counter = c(3, 4))
```

The separator is always the blank space between words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_count()` from the `stringr`  package to count the number of words using the `\\w+` escape pattern.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2), 
  alternativenum = c(342, 5921), 
  text = c("one text here","another text here also"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(counter = str_count(df$text, pattern = "\\w+"))

  id alternativenum                   text counter
1  1            342          one text here       3
2  2           5921 another text here also       4
```